# QuertySelector возвращает null

Tags: c#, anglesharp

В html, который я получаю, есть
`<h2 class="cardHotelDesktop-module__location__k6qvr textLimited-module__textLimited__3L8vc" style="white-space:nowrap">ЧЧ</h2><`
Мой код

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "SS");
   var html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://.....");
   Console.WriteLine(html);
   var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithJs().WithCss();
   var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
   IDocument document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(html));

   var AllIN = document.QuerySelectorAll("li.listCardsHotel-module__item__2CfR-");
 foreach(var el in AllIN)
{
el.QuerySelector("h2.cardHotelDesktop-module__location__k6qvr textLimited-module__textLimited__3L8vc").TextContent;
}
```

Выдает на `QuertySelector` null, хотя в html отображается.
Пробовал чисто из document первый взять такой элемент, тоже null

```
document.QuerySelector("h2.cardHotelDesktop-module__location__k6qvr textLimited-module__textLimited__3L8vc").TextContent;
```

AllIN возвращает мне весь текст, который в этом элементе, а дальше почему-то возвращается Null

Comment: Отладкой надо пользоваться. Ставишь точку останова на `var AllIN = document.QuerySelectorAll("li.listCardsHotel-module__item__2CfR-");` , запускаешь, делаешь шаг вперед,  наводишь мышку на `AllIN`, смотришь есть там хоть какое-то значение?

Comment: @Bulson Суть даже не в том, что в `AllIN` ничего нету, даже когда я хочу сам этот элемент найти, его не ищет, и выдает тоже null, хотя в возвращаемом мне html он есть

Comment: Насколько помню, надо указывать просто имя класса без тега.

Comment: Тоже не помогает. До этого я делал подобное все нормально было, сейчас странно выдает null

Answer (score 0):

Очень странно, за пол года использования anglesharp столкнулся с тем, что `Queryselector()` Видит только Локальное имя или Тег имя.

То есть, когда указываешь класс он возвращает `null`, когда чисто Тег, то все нормально.

Окончательный ответ

```
element.QuerySelector("h2").TextContent
```